# install portable MiKTeX in idea with TeXiFy Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, latex, miktex

How can I configure **[MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/)** ***portable*** in idea with [**TeXiFy**](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9473-texify-idea) plugin?

I tried to setup a build configuration, but the compiler is not found.
MiKTeX is not in the compiler list and pdfLatex is not found.
A custom compiler is not working, I can not select the MiKTeX folder as compiler folder.

The host system is running windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeXiFy dev here. You probably need to configure a [LaTeX SDK](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Latex-Sdk).

1. Open the **project settings** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>).
2. Go to the SDK tab.
3. Click the plus on the top left and select `Add MiKTeX Windows SDK`.
4. Select the path to your portable MiKTeX: `miktex-portable\texmfs\install`.
5. Select the SDK in the Project tab (still in the project settings).
6. In your run configuration select `Use project SDK` for `LaTeX Distribution`.
7. Select a compiler in the `Compiler` dropdown at the top of the run configuration.

I suppose TeXiFy doesn't automatically recognise portable TeX distributions and it's also not added to your path (I guess because what would happen when you disconnect the portable device?), and that's why you have to add it yourself.

If the above doesn't work, it should always be possible to select a custom compiler in the run configuration, using the `Select custom compiler executable path` and specifying the path to your `pdflatex.exe`. Note that you have to specify a specific compiler here, not the parent (MiKTeX) folder.

---

For any problems with TeXiFy in the future I recommend you check the [wiki](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/wiki/Features) or open a [discussion](https://github.com/Hannah-Sten/TeXiFy-IDEA/discussions).
We're more than happy to help, but not very likely to stumble upon SO questions.

Comment: At 4. , the "miktex" directory was created with a "texmfs" folder and miktex-portable.cmd file. I can not find a accepted miktex home directory. How can I fix this issue? - Using now the custom compiler workaround `pdflatex.exe`.

Comment: tested almost every subfolder `install`, `bin`, ...

Comment: I'm guessing from the top of my head: it should be the directory that contains the pdflatex executable, or maybe some parent folder of that so all installed packages are included as well, since we use them for autocompletion. I'll give it a try once I'm at my PC again.

Comment: Selecting the `miktex-portable\texmfs\install` directory works for me. This seems to be the portable equivalent to the `MiKTeX 2.9` directory you get on a regular MiKTeX installation.

Comment: If this still doesn't work for you, what does `where pdflatex` output?

Comment: Thanks. `where` can not work on a portable installation, but `pdflatex.exe` is in `miktex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\ ` . Every folder in this path is not accepted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242646/discussion-between-abby-and-ximi).